# Python 3.9 , autopytoexe, numpy & sklearn gives me a problem. How to solve this?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.9, auto-py-to-exe

I'm using auto-py-to-exe with python 3.9.13 but when running autopy, to make a single file, it gives me this warning:

```
C:\Users\jsgas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:174: UserWarning:

The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.



4597 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): ['C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy.libs']
4597 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.9', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy.libs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy.libs', 'C:\\Users\\jsgas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.9']
```

This is just a warning and not an error, but when running the exe, it gives errors and doesn't run.

this is the error:

```
  File "sklearn\cluster\_spectral.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_dispatcher.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_base.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair'
```

I've tried adding those directories to the variables of the user and the computer but the warning still appears.

I have installed scikit-learn-1.2.0 (the last one), and I use an example from the documents for KMeans in the app (can't show the code, but VS shows as the modules are imported, and when running the app, it doesn't give problems (as a .py)). The problems appears when running the exe.

I don't know what more to do.

Please help.

simple example (this should not let me make a propper exe (this would give errors)

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, 
n_init="auto").fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

Comment: its 7 thousand lines of code ...

Comment: that is why its called a "minimal" reproducible example.

Comment: the error is when calling a module:  duleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair'

Comment: yup... i saw that in your question.

Comment: I just added a minimal example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example I was able to compile using the following steps.

1. Create a clean virtual enviornment and install sklearn and pyinstaller

```
python -m venv venv
venv\scripts\activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller scikit-learn
```

2. I copied your program into `main.py` with some minor alterations.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
                [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0,
    n_init="auto").fit(X)
    print(kmeans.labels_)
    # array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
    print(kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]]))
    # array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
    print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

    # array([[10.,  2.],
        #    [ 1.,  2.]])
```

3. Run `pyinstaller -F --collect-all sklearn main.py`
4. run `dist\main.exe` and I got this as output.

```
[1 1 1 0 0 0]
[1 0]
[[10.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.]]
```

For `auto-py-to-exe` you would do the exact same thing.

After selecting your entry point and choosing all of your other settings, click on the `advanced` tab and choose `collect-all` and add `sklearn` in the line edit field.  Then compile the program.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've never used pyinstaller ... is it possible to add with pyinstaller a manifest? how? also, is it possible to add an icon?

Comment: Hi, I run the pyinstaller ... it didn't gave problems, but the exe did give a problem and the app doesn't start

Comment: @cansado  are you referring to your app or the example code in your question?

Comment: the code is very long, but what I've used is essentially the same as the example ... I just don't understand what, where's the problem with ... woult like to know if some one has had the same problem.

Comment: the error seems to be of the module sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base , is this a module called by the scikitlearn? Do you know what is that? has  any one had the same error or similar?

Comment: Yes it is part of the scikitlearn library.  But it should have been collected with the pyinstaller command in my answer.  Did you try compiling and running the example code in my question to see if it worked properly.  Because if it doesn't that means there is likely something wrong with your instilation

Comment: hi, 0k, yes I tried the example with auto-py and same error appeared (I whant to use auto-py coz I need to add a manifest, and don't know how to do that with pyinstaller)

Comment: I've tried installing python 3.11 adding paths and installling autopy and scikit ... but the problem persists ... what else can I do?